# Preserve class name when wrapping element with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm leveraging the Bootstrap grid so I'm creating components that render elements that include a `class`:

```
const Row = props => (
  <div className="row" {...props}>
    {props.children}
  </div>
);
```

Now, at times I want my row to be padded, so I attempted to wrap my `Row` component:

```
const PaddedRow = styled(Row)`
  padding: 20px;
`;
```

This applies the padding, but when the `div` is rendered, it is without the class.

Chrome's React plugin shows the following:

```
<Styled(Row)>
  <Row className=".sc-cHds hQgwd">
    <div className=".sc-cHds hQgwd">  // No "row" class
```

Is it not possible to preserve the class name for the wrapped component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing with `{...props}` is [spreading the passed-in props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes). `styled-components` passes the generated `className` via these props, and because you apply the spread after your `className` property it overrides the existing class.

If you were to write out manually what your code does in the end this is what it'd look like:

```
<div className="row" className="sc-cHds">
```

This makes it apparent what the issue is: **the second `className` declaration is overriding the first one**! The solution if I were to stick strictly to your code would be to concatenate the passed in class manually:

```
<div {...props} className={`row ${props.className}`}>
```

This works, **however it's not idiomatic usage of `styled-components`**. Rather than wrapping the component with `styled(Row)` we recommend creating a styled component for that `<div />`:

```js
    const RowWrapper = styled.div`
      padding: 20px;
    `

    const Row = props => (
      <RowWrapper className="row">
        {props.children}
      </RowWrapper>
    );
```

This is the way `styled-components` is intended to be used, it will also automatically concatenate your Bootstrap class with the automatically generated one.